# How to use ajax to check unique ID in api and return data based on the unique ID

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, api

I am trying to set up a form that allows users to input an id that they've been given. When the ID is submitted, the back-end is checked to see if that id exists and if it does it returns data

I haven't really tried anything I'm just trying to wrap my mind around how to get this done

Here is the form code:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
Dealership:<br>
<input type="text" name="dealership">
<br>
Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email">
<br><br>
Phone Number:<br>
<input type="text" name="phonenum">
<br><br>
Order ID:<br>
<input type="text" name="order_id">
<br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#works").hide();
var $dealership = $('dealership'); 
var $email = $('email'); 
var $phonenum = $('email');
var $order_id = $('order_id');


$('.submit').click (funciton(){

   var track = {

      dealership : dealership.val(),
      email: email.val(), 
      phonenum = phonenum.val(),
      order_id = order_id.val(),

    }; 

  $.ajax({

    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://testingapi.com/api/order-status',
    data: track, 
    success: function() {
      tracking.append();
    }, 
    sucess: funciton(itWorked) {

  }

  });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be necessary to remove the submit type button and add the button type.

Also, in your code the ID is by class $ (". Submit").
then add the class to the button too.

```
    <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple. Once you've accepted the `order_id` from the user you can pass it along in your data dictionary like this (along with anything else you want to pass):

```
data: {
     'id': order_id,
}
```

On your server side you could so something like this to retrieve the ID:
In PHP:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

In Django:

```
id = request.GET.get('id')
```

Once you've done this you can just query your database and pass this id in the query to check if records match or not.